# How to do sorting using comparison delegate on a string property of a class

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, .net-core

here is my code. I'm trying to do comparison using comparison delegate.(in visual studio code .net core).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace comparisionProject
{
    public class student
    {
        public int SId { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int FullMarks { get; set; }=600;
        public int Marks { get; set; }

    }

    public class tester
    {
        public static int CompareNames(student std1, student std2)
        {
            return std1.name.CompareTo(std1.name);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            student s1 = new student(){SId=101 , name = "kalu",Marks = 456 };
            student s2 = new student(){SId = 102, name = "balu", Marks = 562};
            student s3 = new student(){SId = 103, name= "golu", Marks = 432};
            student s4 = new student(){SId = 104, name= "aalu", Marks = 432};
            List<student> studentList = new List<student>(){s1,s2,s3,s4};
            Comparison<student> stdCompareDelgt = new Comparison<student>(CompareNames);
            studentList.Sort(stdCompareDelgt);
            foreach (student item in studentList)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(item.SId+" "+item.name+" "+item.FullMarks+" " +item.Marks);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

its output

[image]

but, i am expecting the result sorted alphabetically.

Comment: Problem was that `std1` was compared to itself so no sorting took place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you meant:

`return std1.name.CompareTo(std2.name);`

Comment: And did that fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

A more compact way would be using lambdas,

```
studentList.Sort((x, y) => x.name.CompareTo(y.name));
```

Or better, use LINQ,

```
studentList = studentList.OrderBy(o => o.name).ToList();
```

Another solution is to encapsulate the Comparison function within the student object itself, like,

```
public class student : IComparable<student>
{
        public int CompareTo(student other)
        {
            return name.CompareTo(other.name);
        }

  ...
}
```

That way, you can simply do

```
studentList.Sort();
```

And it would use the comparison function you wrote in the student class itself.